# Popup redirected is not working in IE but okay in other browsers

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer, popup, href

I want to open a popup to show winthdraw details.
However it takes me to LOgin page.. not the details page..
in other browsers it works fine, but not in Internet Explorer...

> ```
> > <a href="#" data-withdrawalid="<%# Eval("WithdrawalID") %>"
> > data-status="<%# Eval("Status")%>"                                    
> > data-isfoo="<%#Eval("Isfoo")%>">
> ```

this is how I'm calling it...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[data-withdrawalid]').live("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                var url = "WithdrawalDetails.aspx?WithdrawalID=" + $(this).data('withdrawalid') + "&Status=" + $(this).data('status') + "&Isfoo=" + $(this).data('isfoo') + "&details=true";
                window.open(url, '_blank', 'width=600,height=650,scrollbars=1,toolbar=0,resizable=1');
            });
        });
```

```
function openPopup(url) {
            window.open(url, '_blank', 'width=600,height=650,scrollbars=1,toolbar=0,resizable=1');
        }
```

Comment: What outdated version of jQuery are you using that you are still using `live`? Is the url what you expect?

Comment: @epascarello i wish to go to withdrawDetails with the datavalues passed

Answer (score 0):

I found out the link was blocked in the basic page. so just had to change access permissions.